# Customy WP Query Args are convertet in SQL result

Tags: wp-query

I have a problem with a custom WP_Query. The query args are:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'adressen',
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'adresse_anzeigen_%_anzeige_branche',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value'   => $clientId
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'adresse_anzeigen_%_anzeige_aktiv',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value'   => "1"
        )
    )
);
```

(The meta key pattern are predefined from Advanced Custom Fields)

My Problem in the dump of the WP_Query Object, WordPress converts it to this:

```
SELECT wp_2_posts.* FROM wp_2_posts
INNER JOIN wp_2_postmeta ON ( wp_2_posts.ID = wp_2_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_2_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_2_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 AND
( 
    (
        wp_2_postmeta.meta_key = 'adresse_anzeigen_{783ec3ed63725295bd6fd75a91ca47bfebd15fa5b4aac1ab7eafd49f682034e6}_anzeige_branche' AND
        wp_2_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{783ec3ed63725295bd6fd75a91ca47bfebd15fa5b4aac1ab7eafd49f682034e6}203{783ec3ed63725295bd6fd75a91ca47bfebd15fa5b4aac1ab7eafd49f682034e6}'
    )
    AND 
    (
        mt1.meta_key = 'adresse_anzeigen_{783ec3ed63725295bd6fd75a91ca47bfebd15fa5b4aac1ab7eafd49f682034e6}_anzeige_aktiv' AND
        mt1.meta_value = '1'
    )
)
AND wp_2_posts.post_type = 'adressen'
AND
(
    wp_2_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR
    wp_2_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR
    wp_2_posts.post_status = 'private'
)
GROUP BY wp_2_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_2_posts.post_title ASC
```

The % sign and the quotes are not numbers? Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [dev note for 4.8.3](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/10/31/changed-behaviour-of-esc_sql-in-wordpress-4-8-3/) implies, you need to unescape the escaped % by using the `$wpdb->remove_placeholder_escape` method. Something like

```
global $wpdb;
add_filter('posts_request',array($wpdb, 'remove_placeholder_escape'));
```

Very untested.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour since WP 4.8.3, where the % sign is encoded to prevent some forms of SQL injection. Here is the discussion about it, and other user reported the same problem: [4.8.3 prepare update](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/10/31/changed-behaviour-of-esc_sql-in-wordpress-4-8-3/).